# Parsing date strings using google apps script

Tags: timestamp, google-apps-script

I'm new to google apps script, and I'm having trouble parsing date strings from a UiApp form. In this instance, I'm writing a script to allow the user to filter a timestamped spreadsheet within a specified date range.

My problem is that the code below returns an invalid date object when passed a date string (from a text box named `dateFromField`) in the conventional javascript format `YYYY,M,D` (i.e. `2012,1,2` for Feb 2, 2012):

```
function dateFilter(e) {
  var fromDate = new Date(e.parameter.dateFromField);
}
```

I've checked that the `e.parameter.dateFromField` correctly returns the given string (`Logger.log(e.parameter.dateFromField);` returns `2012,1,2`), and that its type is string (rather than object).

However, if I type the date string into the function directly, i.e.:

```
function dateFilter(e) {
  var fromDate = new Date(2012,1,2);
}
```

I get valid a date object. I don't understand the difference between these two examples - as far as I can tell they are equivalent; in both instances the string `2012,1,2` is being passed to the `new Date` function. I'm obviously missing something simple - can anyone tell me what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you typed it manually, you actually passed 3 number parameters, not a string with a list of comma separated numbers.

I guess you could just split your parameter before passing, e.g.

```
var dateParts = e.parameter.dataFromField.split(',');
var fromDate = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1], dateParts[2]);
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple, but that's just embarrassing. Thank you for indulging me - your solution worked beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using either the DateBox and DatePicker classes in UiApp instead of a text box. They return an actual date object therefore eliminating the need to parse at all. They were just added to the Apps Script documentation. See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_datebox).

Comment: So they have! Using those will certainly make things easier - thanks for the tip.

Comment: but are now deprecated?