# Error "Invalid Date" in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I have tried to adapt this answer [Parsing date strings using google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660131/parsing-date-strings-using-google-apps-script)  but I am lost !

```
function test_t(){

var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm");
var date = (new Date(formattedDate)).toDateString();

// // //var dateParts = formattedDate.split('-');
//var dateParts = formattedDate.split(',');
//var fromDate = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1], dateParts[2], dateParts[3]);


Logger.log(date)
}
```

Thanks in advance ;)

**Edit: My apologies. I'll try to be more explicit hereafter :**

The following works. The result is fine : 2014-08-19-1350.

```
function test_t4(){
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm");
Logger.log(formattedDate)
}
```

But when I use the same thing into a more complex code I have the same "Invalid Date" error in the filename.

```
function copyModel2() {
// The code tries to create a new spreadsheet (renamed with text+date-and-time) into a specific folder 
//(inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418109/how-can-i-create-spreadsheet-and-open-it-automaticclly)


var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm");
var date = (new Date(formattedDate)).toDateString();

var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0A...key..5UFE");
var ssname = source.getSheetByName("main").getRange("A1").getValues(); 
var date_ssname = ssname +"_"+ date


//var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByID('0B...folderID....U');   // For some reasons I have always an error if I use the correct folder ID
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('specific_folder_name'); // replace by the right folder name, assuming there is only one folder with this name

var destination = SpreadsheetApp.create(date_ss_name);

// result for the new sheet name: "rangeA1text_Invalid Date"
// desired result : rangeA1text_2014-08-19-1343


// I succeeded in creating the correct spreadsheet name once but any other trials leads to "rangeA1text_Invalid Date" error in the spreadsheet filename.
}
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you simplified too much Henrique's answer...

here is how it works :

```
function test_t(){

  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm");
  var dateParts = formattedDate.split('-');
  var date = (new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1]-1, dateParts[2], dateParts[3], dateParts[4],0,0)).toDateString();

  // new Date is defined with parameters year,month,day,hours,minutes,seconds, milliseconds as separate integers
  Logger.log(date)
}
```

### EDIT following your comment

just like that (comments in code):

```
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm");// this is a string, not a date anymore >> you can use it directly to build the name of your file.

var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0A...key..5UFE");
var ssname = source.getSheetByName("main").getRange("A1").getValues(); 
var date_ssname = ssname +"_"+ formattedDate
```

Comment: Many thanks Serge. ;) But I have this result in log : "Fri Sep 19 2014". I was expecting that : "2014-08-19-1317". Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Ooops, yes, sorry... I forgot month count from 0, code edited !

Comment: Many thanks Serge. ;) Your code result is "Tue Aug 19 2014". I tought I could have it into another format like "2014-08-19-1401". But I realize that it is my fault as my question was not detailed enough! So I have added an edit. With my apologies. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Btw, you should replace GMT +2 with Session.getScriptTimeZone() to avoid issues when summer time will end. :-) After October it will become GMT+1 ...

Comment: Many thanks Serge ! Following your suggestion I have added this code : `var timezone = Session.getScriptTimeZone()
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmms");` It works like a charm. Many thanks again. ;)